# escaping special regex character in cypress

Tags: javascript, regex, html-table, cypress, escaping

I have working regex at regex101.com for my use case which is to only match on a six digit numeric string that is enclosed in parenthesis. My attempts to use that regex in a table row contains selector are having no luck. They are either not escaping the parentheses & returning rows that should not match. Or they find no match when they should find matches. On regex101.com, the working expression is `/\([0-9]{6}\)/gm`. I've tried double backslashes since JS backslash is itself a special character. That is over-matching & including rows that merely have a six digit numeric string (no parentheses). Any better suggestions appreciated.

```js
cy.contains(
  'div[id="driverTableContainer"] table tbody tr',
  new RegExp("\\([0-9]{6}\\)", 'g')
)
  .nextAll()
  .then(($el) => {
    cy.task('log', $el.text())
  })
```

Comment: You don't have to call `RegExp` if your regex doesn't have any dynamic elements. Just use literal syntax: `/\(\d{6}\)/g`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to escape the backslash, this works (presuming your element selector works)

```js
cy.contains(
  'div[id="driverTableContainer"] table tbody tr',
  new RegExp('\([0-9]{6}\)')
)
```

You don't need the `g` since `cy.contains()` passes for 1 or more occurances of the string.

Also, `cy.contains()` only returns the first row found. If you want multiple rows, you need to `cy.get()` then filter

```js
const re = new RegExp('\([0-9]{6}\)')
cy.get('div[id="driverTableContainer"] table tbody tr')
  .filter((index, el) => re.test(el.innerText))
```